# Getting the error ',' expected in JQuery click Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write a jquery function on button click nut it's showing an error **','** expected.

------Code-------

```
 $("#submit").click(funtion(){
         if ($("#totalizerform").valid())
        {
            return true;
        }
         else
         {

           return false;
         }
        });
```

Comment: `funtion` -> `function`

Comment: In addition to what @PredatorIWD said you should be using the new 'on' syntax.

Comment: thanks, man this programming makes me mad

Comment: @Aaron, the "new" on syntax exists for ages. But, yes.. use that instead.

Comment: Wrong phrasing I guess :D @entiendoNull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please give this a go:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
  if ($("#totalizerform").valid()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```